# Como remover um Node do database, usando Firebase Realtime Database para Unity

Tags: firebase, unity3d, realtime-database

Eu uso listas sincronizadas com Firebase Realtime Database for Unity e eu estou precisando dar uma melhorada nelas.
Eu preciso encontrar uma maneira de deletar um unico Item da lista sem ter que:

1. Baixar a Lista toda.
2. Remover o Item localmente.
3. Enviar a Lista toda de volta para o banco de dados.

Eu tentei usar o DatabaseReference.RemoveValueAsync(), mas esse método apenas muda o valor do Nódulo/Nó(Node) para *null*.
Eu uso o Json Utility para traduzir de Json para minhas Classes Customizadas, o problema é que ao se deparar com o valor *null* o meu código simplesmente cria uma Classe Customizada Padrão.
Isso faz com que toda vez que eu deleto um item, ele ainda apareça na lista. Só que sem os dados.

Eu poderia simplesmente, ao me deparar com o *null*, não adicionar ele a Lista local. Mas, esse Item ainda existe no servidor e fazer isso faria com que a Lista Local e a Lista do servidor ficassem desiguais.

Eu poderia checar se o item esta sem dados e chegar a conclusão de que ele esta deletado. Mas isso parece meio bagunçado.

Alguem sabe algum jeito de deletar um Nódulo/Nó(Node) ao invés de mudar o valor dele para *null*?

Lembrando que eu uso Firebase Realtime Database for Unity.

Comment: Favor colocar o conteúdo em português.

Comment: Queria postar no stack global, tem como você mover pra la?

Comment: Desculpe, mas não tenho este poder, vai ter que copiar e colar mesmo :P

Comment: Também vou ter que esperar 1 hora e meia. -_-
O erro foi meu de qualquer jeito. Vou traduzir a pergunta, quem sabe o pessoal daqui me ajuda também.

Comment: Assim que você traduzir, envie mais uma mensagem aqui nos comentários, assim eu vou começar uma votação para reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: Traduzida... :)

Comment: Infelizmente, o Firebase ainda não tem como: 1. Remover um item sem baixar toda a lista; 2. Remover um item do servidor e manter o item local.